# Why toggle class not working in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
 <form method="POST" class="Main_Window" id="Main_form">
        <p class="animated bounceInLeft">Name :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>
        <input type="text" id="Name" class="animated bounceInRight" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
        <br><br>
        <p class="animated bounceInDown"> Odd/Even:</p>
        <select class="animated bounceInUp">
            <option value="odd">Odd</option>            
            <option value="even">Even</option>            
        </select>
        <br>
        <a class="animated bounceInRight" onclick="toggleClass();"><span class="tooltip" title="Click To Play!"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="play" width="119.91" height="119.91"><path fill="#E74C3C" d="M58.8 10.8c-27.77 0-50.3 22.5-50.3 50.3 0 27.78 22.53 50.3 50.3 50.3 27.8 0 50.32-22.52 50.32-50.3 0-27.8-22.53-50.3-50.3-50.3zm0 97.97c-26.32 0-47.66-21.34-47.66-47.67 0-26.34 21.34-47.68 47.67-47.68 26.37 0 47.7 21.34 47.7 47.67 0 26.3-21.33 47.64-47.66 47.64z"/><path fill="#E74C3C" d="M58.8 21.12c-22.07 0-39.97 17.9-39.97 39.98s17.9 39.98 39.98 39.98c22.1 0 40-17.9 40-39.98s-17.9-39.98-40-39.98zm3.52 50.7L43.77 82.47l.04-21.37.07-21.37 18.5 10.72 18.5 10.72L62.3 71.82z"/></svg></span></a>
        <script>
            function toggleClass() {
                document.getElementById("play").classList.toggle('goDown');
                $("#Main_form").toggleClass("Main_Window", "Main_Window_1");
                $("#m2").toggleClass("Main_window2_2", "Main_window2");
            }
        </script>
    </form>
    <!-- This form is provided when the same player plays the match It is decided by the face detector-->
    <form method="POST" class="Main_window2_2" id="m2">
        <p class="animated bounceInLeft"> Enter Your Number</p>
        <input type="number" class="animated bounceInRight">
        <!-- Two labels to display the cpu and the provided number-->
        <br>
        <p class="animated bounceInDown"> Bat/Bow:</p>
        <select class="animated bounceInUp">
            <option value="bat">Batting</option>            
            <option value="bow">Bowling</option>            
        </select>
        <a class="animated bounceInRight" onclick="toggleClass();"><span class="tooltip" title="Click To Play!"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="play" width="119.91" height="119.91"><path fill="#E74C3C" d="M58.8 10.8c-27.77 0-50.3 22.5-50.3 50.3 0 27.78 22.53 50.3 50.3 50.3 27.8 0 50.32-22.52 50.32-50.3 0-27.8-22.53-50.3-50.3-50.3zm0 97.97c-26.32 0-47.66-21.34-47.66-47.67 0-26.34 21.34-47.68 47.67-47.68 26.37 0 47.7 21.34 47.7 47.67 0 26.3-21.33 47.64-47.66 47.64z"/><path fill="#E74C3C" d="M58.8 21.12c-22.07 0-39.97 17.9-39.97 39.98s17.9 39.98 39.98 39.98c22.1 0 40-17.9 40-39.98s-17.9-39.98-40-39.98zm3.52 50.7L43.77 82.47l.04-21.37.07-21.37 18.5 10.72 18.5 10.72L62.3 71.82z"/></svg></span></a>
        <script>
            function toggleClass() {
                document.getElementById("play").classList.toggle('goDown');
                $("#m2").addClass("Main_window2_2");
                $('#p3').addClass("playing_window");
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```

This is the code i wrote where the javascript that toggle the class name doesn't work when i click the button?
Can You please rectify the above query?
I have included all the required js files in it
There is no error in the console

Comment: Didn't found end </form> tag. Are you missing some code to share?

Comment: Don't disseminate `<script>` tags around the document. Keep them all in one place, right before the closing `</body>` tag. - Then you'll probably notice that you have two `toggleClass` functions...

Comment: Also, decide what you want to use. If you want JS, use JS and get rid of jQuery.

Comment: Avoid using inline JS like `onclick=""` use `Element.addEventListener()`, again, in the bottom of your document.

Comment: I have made different function names and placed all the script tags right before the closing tag of body though i am not getting the result!

Comment: @Tonystar I know you're still not getting the needed result. Why do you have duplicated IDs? For example: `id="play"` you know when to use ID and when to use classes? ID should be **unique**. That's why it's called ID.

Comment: You don't have to toggle two classes: `"Main_Window", "Main_Window_1"` why? You only need default form styles and a single class that overrides the defaults in CSS.

Comment: Also, what is `$('#p3')` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Though i changed the id's in "id = play" to "id = play_1" nothing changes the outuput of the page?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i can't provide my full code in this question so i have three forms in it

Comment: @Tonystark I'm not sure what are you building, but anyway. If you have N forms, programming is not about copy/pasting functions and assigning slightly modified (suffixed) numbers to classes or IDs to elements and variables or CSS classes. You should try to create a single function that can handle an infinite number of forms. And you need only one special style class - if I 'm guessing right that you're creating some sort of paginated forms...

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/TONYSTARK-EDITH/HandCricket/blob/master/hc.html ) It is the full code will you please check this code and tell me what to do!

Comment: In your github example 1. place every single piece of JavaScript into a single `<script>` tag right **before** the closing `</body>` tag. 2. Make sure that you don't have duplicated IDs. 3. Don't use unnecessary classes. That's for a start.

Comment: What are those classes for? i.e: `Main_window2_2` , `playing_window` etc? You use them to toggle forms visibility?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes i use them to toggle form visibility

Comment: Don't use `<script>` tags in `<head>` at least not without deferring them. Place all script tags at the bottom.

Comment: Humm... why do you use `<form>`? You have plans to submit data to server?

Comment: [link] (github.com/TONYSTARK-EDITH/HandCricket/blob/master/hc.html) @RokoC.Buljan i have updated what you said and i added the style.css file to it. Nope I don't want to submit data to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to recap, summarize and minimalize your code:

- You have three *"windows"* (don't use `<form>` if you don't submit anything to the server)
- The first tho have a button to go-to the next window (at least as far as I can see)
- You need a `.is-active` class to style the currently active  *"window"*:

```js
// get all .window and .next buttons elements
const ELS_window = document.querySelectorAll(".window");
const ELS_next = document.querySelectorAll(".next");
let current = 0; // The current window index

const nextWindow = () => {
  current += 1;
  current %= ELS_window.length; // Loop-back to 0 if needed
  ELS_window.forEach((el, i) => el.classList.toggle('is-active', i == current));
}

ELS_next.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", nextWindow));
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body {height:100%; font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 20vw;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  border: 2px solid #777;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.window.is-active { /* just one class! */
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="window is-active"><!-- NOTICE! only one special .is-active class! -->
  <h2>WINDOW 1</h2>
  <button class="next" type="button">NEXT</button>
</div>

<div class="window">
  <h2>WINDOW 2</h2>
  <button class="next" type="button">PLAY</button>
</div>

<div class="window">
  <h2>GAME</h2>
  <button class="next" type="button">Exit game</button>
</div>
```

the above will work for an infinite number of `.window` elements.